# Table cell stretching

Tags: cell, stretch

I have two columns in my table with equal width (50%, 50%).
I am showing search results URL in them. For big urls the columns are stretching and destroying the layout.

Any suggestion to the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SEE **[How to wrap long lines without spaces in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363425/how-to-wrap-long-lines-without-spaces-in-html)**

These may help too:

[Best word wrap algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586/best-word-wrap-algorithm)

[Word-wrap in an HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-a-html-table)

Answer (score 0):

You can set `text-overflow:ellipsis;` described [here](http://www.blakems.com/archives/000077.html) and/or use [jQuery ellipsis plugin](http://devongovett.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/text-overflow-ellipsis-for-firefox-via-jquery/).