# How to wrap a long text having no spaces in php

Tags: php, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to wrap long lines without spaces in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363425/how-to-wrap-long-lines-without-spaces-in-html)

I have a long text "jkjkllllllllljcsccncnmchdkcjhvcjdkvk".how to wrap this text in php

Comment: You can't really *wrap* text that has no spaces, unless you just pick an arbitrary point and split it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
<?php
$iamlong = "woooooooooooord.";
$iamwrapped = wordwrap($iamlong , 8, "<br>", true);

echo $iamwrapped;
?>
```