# Is it possible to indent wrapped lines within code blocks via CSS?

Tags: css

I have some code inside an HTML document. The code itself is not important – I've used lorem ipsum to make this clear.

```
<pre><code>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Sed sit amet diam sit amet sem accumsan faucibus ac in arcu.
Quisque varius, erat vel euismod ornare, libero orci laoreet velit, at lobortis sem nisl et eros.</code></pre>
```

I've applied `white-space: pre-wrap` to the code block to force long lines to wrap as necessary. I'd like to know whether it's possible to indent the wrapped portion of the wrapped lines, to give something like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Sed sit amet diam sit amet sem accumsan faucibus ac in arcu.
Quisque varius, erat vel euismod ornare, libero orci laoreet velit,
        at lobortis sem nisl et eros.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately after much searching I've come to believe that this is currently impossible using CSS alone. What's required is a pseudo-element for each "line" (text matching `/^.*$/m`), which would enable the indentation of lines **beyond the first** to be controlled via CSS.

I raised this issue on the www-style mailing list. [fantasai's responses](http://old.nabble.com/%22Line%22-pseudo-element-required-to-control-indentation-of--pre-formatted-text--td29768752.html#a29777907) are promising, particularly the suggestion that the `text-indent` property could be extended to allow `text-indent: 2em hanging each-line`.

Comment: I believe XHTML 2.0 wanted to introduce `<l>line</l>` as a replacement for `<br />` but it fizzled out for want of an upgrade path.

Comment: What's really ideal is to be able to indent by a variable amount such that a wrapped line is always indented more than the initial line... but in a CSS-only solution, I'd settle for a fixed indent.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing, and after enabling the flag in Chrome, `text-indent: 2em hanging each-line` seems to only apply to `<p>` tags, and not `<code>` elements.  Maybe someday though!

Answer (score 13):

It is kind of possible... I'm not using using the `<pre>` and `<code>` tags and I'm not sure how important these tags are to you... but I've been able to get the style you're looking for and mimick the formatting as best as I could. Check it out.

http://jsfiddle.net/PVZW5/7/

### CSS

```
div {
    margin-left:24px;
    width:400px;
}

p {
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin:0 28px;
    text-indent: -28px;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p>Sed sit amet diam sit amet sem accumsan faucibus ac in arcu.</p>
    <p>Quisque varius, erat vel euismod ornare, libero orci laoreet velit, at lobortis sem nisl et eros.</p>
</div>
```

Take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330229/how-to-apply-a-line-wrapcontinuation-style-with-css) and [some solutions](http://tardate.com/line-wrap-continuations.htm) that have come from it. It is relevant to your question. It might be worth your time to take a look :)

I hope this helps!

Comment: This doesn't respect line breaks within the code block, unfortunately. The start of _every_ line should be flush left, not just the first line within the code block. I appreciate the jsfiddle link, though.

Comment: @davidchambers... I didn't realize that you had new lines in your code. I'll go back and see if I can do it.

Comment: @davidchambers... please take a look at my post. I updated the link with the new solution as well as the CSS and HTML. I hope this helps you. If this isn't what you're looking for... then I don't think you can do what you using only CSS. You might have to resort to JavaScript (I recommend jQuery).

Comment: While I appreciate the links, defiling code snippets with paragraph tags (or tags of any nature) is not an option I'm willing to consider. Now that I'm fairly sure that I haven't overlooked an obvious solution I plan to raise this issue on the www-style mailing list.

Comment: @davidchambers "Defiling" code snippets? Not an option you're willing to consider? This isn't going to ruin the code somehow; people use markup in their code all the time, if they want to to group it together into logical pieces which may be styled (see, for instance, the syntax highlighting of code snippets here on StackOverflow). I don't think you're going to get much traction on www-style suggesting something that can simply be solved by marking up your paragraphs instead of relying on white-space for your paragraph boundaries.

Comment: I guess you could do this with some JavaScript (or jQuery), but as far as a PURE CSS solution, I don't think one exists as far as I know. Please let me know if the "www-style" mailing list people get back to you.

Comment: Brian, please note that the "lorem ipsum" in this perfunctory example is representative of programming code (a Python snippet, perhaps) rather than prose. While I completely agree that marking up prose using paragraph tags and the like is the correct approach, appropriate semantics do not exist for marking up code. This is nice, in a way, since the only markup that one need apply to a code snippet is `<pre><code>` ... `</code></pre>`. The downside, though, is a lack of styling hooks; a suitable pseudo-element would solve this problem.

Comment: Hristo: Will do! (I've been waiting to see whether someone would provide a CSS-only solution in this thread. I've now accepted that currently such a solution almost certainly does not exist, so I'll raise the issue on the mailing list and report back.)

Comment: @Brian... sounds good. Looking forward to hearing what the CSS people have to say

Comment: @davidchambers Yes, I realize that it's a stand-in for code. My point was that it won't break anything to use a tag like `<p>` for formatting your code, especially for a case like this, in which you want to treat each line as a separately indented paragraph. And you will need to add more tags to your code if you want to do anything like syntax-highlighting.

Comment: The www-style thread is at http://old.nabble.com/%22Line%22-pseudo-element-required-to-control-indentation-of--pre-formatted-text--td29768752.html. fantasai's comments are promising, particularly that which suggests extending the `text-indent` property to allow `text-indent: 2em hanging each-line`.

Answer (score 6):

```
text-indent: -2em;
padding-left: 2em;
```

Comment: This doesn't respect line breaks within the code block, unfortunately.

Comment: I think you meant it doesn't behave as you wanted it :-) If you want a new line "unindented", you should make it a paragraph, i.e. <p>, and style it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this works in `<pre>`, but it looks promising.

http://www.ehow.com/how_2382848_hanging-indent-css.html

Comment: This approach would work if each line of code were in its own element. Some JavaScript syntax highlighters replace code blocks with ordered lists, allowing CSS to control the indentation of wrapped lines. I'm seeking a CSS-only solution, however.

Comment: Link seems broken

Answer (score 0):

Not currently possible just with CSS, but with the help of a scripting language ...

**PHP**

```
echo '<pre id="the_pre_id"><div>'.str_replace("\n",'</div><div>',$text).'</div>';
```

or **JavaScript**

```
var el = document.getElementById('the_pre_id');
el.innerHTML='<div>'+el.innerHTML.replace(/\n/g, '</div><div>')+'</div>';
```

*Note, you only need to choose one of the above snippets.  Both accomplish the same thing.*

We pollute the markup (non-semantic tags), but it allows us to create per-line style rules:

**CSS**

```
pre{
    white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
    word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
pre > div {
    padding-left: 1em;
    text-indent: -1em;
}
```

And we have exactly the effect you're looking for ...

### Result

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur  
>      adipiscing elit. 
>   De malis autem et bonis ab iis animalibus,  
>      quae nondum depravata sint, ait optime
>      iudicari.
>   Quae cum praeponunt, ut sit aliqua rerum  
>      selectio, naturam videntur sequi; Quasi 
>      ego id curem, quid ille aiat aut neget.

Comment: Looks great, but copying it gets the blank spaces `&nbsp;` that is forced into this.

Answer (score 0):

This article has a solution using the first-of-type pseudo selector that seems to work so far for me: http://thenewcode.com/50/Classic-Typography-Effects-in-CSS-Hanging-Indent

```css
html{
  margin-left: 100px;
}
p {
 margin: 6em inital;
  width: 300px;
}
p:first-of-type {
 text-indent: -4em;
}
```

```html
<p>Leverage agile frameworks to provide a robust synopsis for high level 
overviews. Iterative approaches to corporate strategy foster collaborative
  thinking to further the overall value proposition.</p>
<p>Bring to the table win-win survival strategies to ensure proactive domination. 
At the end of the day, going forward, a new normal that has evolved from 
generation X is on the runway heading towards a streamlined cloud solution. 
  User generated content in real-time will have multiple touchpoints for offshoring.</p>
```

Comment: That's a useful technique but it does not answer the question. The question asks about targeting wrapped lines *within in single element*.