# Line wrap in list element

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to indent wrapped lines within code blocks via CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477625/is-it-possible-to-indent-wrapped-lines-within-code-blocks-via-css)

Is there a way to make text lines align under each other in list elements?

[image]

Comment: By default, lists typically look like your 2nd example, with `list-style-position: outside`.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/list-style-position

Comment: Hmm, that's what I thought, but I may have some other class interfering... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this CSS:

```
li { list-style-position: outside; }
```